# Entire script refuses to execute when include a while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm trying to write a very basic script which gets the hostname of every device on the local network and prints the ip address of the hostname which matches my specification. however the code simply doesn't run. After a bit of trial and error, i realised that everything in the code works fine WITHOUT the while loop, but once it is included, it's as if nothing is even written in the file. I have no idea why this is happening

```
import socket, pyperclip
myPC = socket.gethostname()
hostName = ''
ipEnd = 0
while str(hostName[0]) != myPC:
    ipEnd += 1
    hostName = str(socket.gethostbyaddr('192.168.0.' + str(ipEnd)))
    pyperclip.copy('afterloop')
print(ipEnd)
```

**EDIT:**
new code (still faulty) looks like this:

```
import socket, pyperclip
myPC = socket.gethostname()
hostName = 'placeholder'
ipEnd = 0
while hostName[0] != myPC:
    ipEnd += 1
    hostName = socket.gethostbyaddr('192.168.0.' + str(ipEnd))
    pyperclip.copy('afterloop')
print(ipEnd)
```

Comment: `str(hostName[0])` is wrong!

Comment: As @DirtyBit mentioned, you cannot iterate over a empty string using indices. You need to use a suitable initialization.

Comment: @SuperKogito could you explain that in a bit more detail? I am very beginner so i have no idea what that means

Comment: This initialization `hostName = ''` is not compatible with `str(hostName[0])`. Since your `hostName` has 0 elements, you cannot use an index to access elements in `hostName`.

Comment: @JoePringle I suggest you open a new question if you're unsure about your code after reading the documentation on [Handing Exceptions](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some notes to try:

1. Initialise the hostname with the first IP:

```
ip_end = 1
hostname = socket.gethostbyaddr('192.168.0.{}'.format(ip_end))
```

This will help avoid any strange behaviour at the start. As a side note I've changed your code slightly to be better in line with naming conventions/string formatting just for your knowledge.

2. `socket.gethostbyaddr` returns a tuple of `(hostname, aliaslist, ipaddrlist)` however you are converting the entire thing into a `str`. This means that when you do `hostname[0]` you are only taking the first character of the string (in this case a `(`).

   Try changing your `while` loop to look something like

```
import socket, pyperclip
my_pc = socket.gethostname()
ip_end = 1
hostname = socket.gethostbyaddr('192.168.0.{}'.format(ip_end))[0]
while hostname != my_pc:
  ip_end += 1
  hostname = socket.gethostbyaddr('192.168.0.{}'.format(ip_end))[0]
  pyperclip.copy('afterloop')
print(ip_end)
```